# Align text after n-th column in vim removing unnecessary blanks

Tags: vim

In vim, in a Windows machine (with no access to "unix"-like commands such command column) I want to reformat this code to make it more readable:

```
COLUMN KEY_ID       FORMAT 9999999999
COLUMN VALUE_1                           FORMAT 99
COLUMN VALUE_2                            FORMAT 99
COLUMN VALUE_3              FORMAT 999
COLUMN VALUE_4        FORMAT 999
```

And I want to have this using as less commands as possible:

```
COLUMN KEY_ID      FORMAT 9999999999
COLUMN VALUE_1     FORMAT 99
COLUMN VALUE_2     FORMAT 99
COLUMN VALUE_3     FORMAT 999
COLUMN VALUE_4     FORMAT 999
```

Note this is just an excerpt, as there many more lines in which I must do the same.

Comment: Install the [tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) plugin and run `:Tabularize`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the following command:

```
:%s/\w\zs\s*\zeFORMAT/^I
```

The pattern will match the whitespaces between `FORMAT` and the end of the previous word and replace it by a tab:

```
\w      Any 'word' character
\zs     Start the matching
\s*     Any number of whitespace
\ze     End the matching
FORMAT  The actual word format
```

`\zs` and `\ze` allow to apply the substitution only on the whitespaces see: [`:h /\zs`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5Czs) and [`:h /\ze`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5Cze)

Note that `^I` should be inserted with <kbd>ctrl+v</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>

The [tabular plugin](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) recommended by @SatoKatsura would be a good way to do it too.

---

You can also generalize that. Let's say you have the following file:

```
COLUMN KEY_ID           FORMAT 9999999999
COLUMN VALUE_1                      FOO 99
COLUMN VALUE_2      BAR 99
```

You could use this command:

```
:%s/^\(\w*\s\)\{1}\w*\zs\s*\ze/
```

Were the pattern can be detailed like that:

```
^                 Match the beginning of the line
\(\w*\s\)\{1}     One occurrence of the pattern \w*\s i.e. one column
\w*               Another column
\zs\s*\ze         The whitespaces after the previous column
```

You could change the value of `\{1}` to apply the command on the next columns.

---

**EDIT** to answer @aturegano comment, here is a way to align the column to another one:

```
%s/^\(\w*\s\)\{1}\w*\zs\s*\ze/\=repeat(' ', 30-matchstrpos(getline('.'), submatch(0))[1])
```

The idea is still to match the whitespaces which must be aligned, on the second part of the substitution command we use a sub-replace-expression (See [`:h sub-replace-expression`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#sub-replace-expression)).

This allows us to use a command from the substitution part, which can be explained like this:

```
\=                 Interpret the next characters as a command
repeat(' ', XX)    Replace the match with XX whitespaces

XX is decomposed like this:
30-                 30 less the next expression
matchstrpos()[1]    Returns the columns where the second argument appears in the first one
getline('.')        The current line (i.e. the one containing the match
submatch(0)         The matched string
[1]                 Necessary since matchstrpos() returns a list:
                       [matchedString, StartPosition, EndPosition]
                    and we are looking for the second value.
```

You then simply have to replace 30 by the column where you want to move your next column.

See [`:h matchstrpos()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#matchstrpos%28%29), [`:h getline()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#getline()) and [`:h submatch()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#submatch())

Comment: Very good approach and detailed explanation. I did not mentioned above that I don't want to add any tab in the code. The expression `:%s/^\(\w*\s\)\{1}\w*\zs\s*\ze/` matches what I want to modify, is there any way to specify "fill with spaces up to column n"?

Comment: @aturegano I think that for such a use case, the tabular plugin would be the easiest way. Maybe you can hack something thanks to the sub-replace-expression ([`:h sub-replace-expression`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#sub-replace-expression)): you'd replace the second part `/^I` by `/\=something` where `something` would be a test of the column an the number to whitespaces to add but I'm not sure that is possible.

Comment: @aturegano I found a solution, see my edit and tell me if that's want you wanted :-)

Comment: Alternatively: `:g/^COLUMN/ s/.*/\=call('printf', ['%s %-30s %s %s'] + split(submatch(0)))/`

Comment: @statox After your edition, the answer is completely solved. Thanks for the detailed explanations. Please do not delete any of the previous attemps you have written in you answer, I consider them valueable.

Comment: @SatoKatsura maybe you should make it an answer because that it much more elegant than my solution.

Comment: @statox [`matchstrpos()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#matchstrpos%28%29) was included in Vim 8 but your link is pointing to the Vim 7.3 documentation.

Comment: @JairLópez: Thanks for pointing it out. I have a function which automatically generates these links, I really should update it :-)

Answer (score 2):

For alignment, there are three well-known plugins:

- the venerable [Align - Help folks to align text, eqns, declarations, tables, etc](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=294)
- the modern [tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular)
- the contender [vim-easy-align](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4520)

Answer (score 2):

Posting an answer as requested:

```
:g/^COLUMN / s/.*/\=call('printf', ['%s %-30s %s %s'] + split(submatch(0)))/
```

Explanation:

- `g/^COLUMN /` - apply the following command to lines matching `/^COLUMN /` (cf. `:h :global`)
- `\=` - replace with the result of evaluating an expression, rather than with a fixed string (cf. `:h s/\=`)
- `submatch(0)` - the line being matched
- `split(...)` -  split line into words
- `printf(...)` - format the line
- `call(...)` - we'd like to have `printf('%s %-30s %s %s', list)`, but `printf()` doesn't take "real" lists as arguments, so we have to unfold the list with a `call(...)` (cf. `:h call()`).

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution:

```
:%s/ \{2,}/   /g
```

This solution is not perfect because the result will have an extra single space on the first line. To fix this problem:

```
:%s/\%>15c \{2,}/   /g
```

**Explanation of pattern:**

```
%>15c\s\{2,}

%>15c                 Matches only after column 15

     \s\{2,}          Matches two or more white spaces
```